# Как сделать чтобы вводимые пользователем данные заносились в словарь и не удалялись, когда запускаешь снова прогу

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
text = input("Введите текст для зашифровки : ")
key = random.getrandbits(15)
print("Ваш ключ для получения доступа к тексту : ", key)
key_list = {key : text}
```

программа написана на python 3.6. 
при каждом новом запуске программы словарь заменяет уже существующие данные. Как сделать, чтобы он не удалял старые данные и просто записывал в словарь новые? Помогите плиззз :з

Comment: Сохраняйте словарь в отдельный файл, а при старте программы вычитывайте его из этого файла.

Answer (score 0):

Сделай работу с файлом. При каждом запуске программа будет открывать файл, читать его и записывать новые ключи и значения.

Answer (score 0):

txt - текстовый файл, создаётся в папке с Пайтоном, той же папке где python.exe

```
import random

text = input("Введите текст для зашифровки : ")
key = random.getrandbits(15)
print("Ваш ключ для получения доступа к тексту : ", key)
key_list = {key : text}

def saveDict():
    with open("hello.txt", "a") as fileW: #открывает существующий или создает новый файл
        for key, value in key_list.items():
           fileW.write(f"{key}::{value}\n")
           fileW.write(f"{key}::{value}\n")

    fileW.close

def openDict():
    try:
        with open("hello.txt", "r") as fileR:
            try:
                list = fileR.readlines()
                listN = []

                for i in range(len(list)):
                    list[i] = list[i][:len(list[i])-1]
                    listN.append(list[i].split("::"))
                    listN[i][0] = int(listN[i][0])
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            finally:
                fileR.close
                return dict(listN)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

saveDict() #Сохранение новых данных в словарь в файл hello.txt

key_list = openDict() #Чтение данных из hello.txt, возвращает данные
#в виде словаря {key : text}
print(key_list)
```